# Parsing log files with « R »

Tags: r, csv, import

I'd like to get all source IPs from some firewall logs.

First, which import method do you recommend when it comes to import logs that have different row size?

Sample rawdata:

```
Sep  7 13:10:01 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX id=firewall time="2018-09-07 13:10:01" fw="XXXXX-ISSP" tz=+0200 startime="2018-09-07 13:10:00" pri=5 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=102 srcif="vlan3" srcifname="XXXXX" ipproto=tcp dstif="vlan6" dstifname="XXXXX" proto=tcp5666 src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX srcport=55617 srcportname=ephemeral_fw_tcp srcname=XXXXX.service.noissp.XXXXX.corp srcmac=YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY dst=10.95.160.7 dstport=5666 dstportname=tcp5666 dstname=XXXXX.biz.noissp.XXXXX.corp modsrc=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX modsrcport=55617 origdst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX origdstport=5666 ipv=4 sent=1412 rcvd=1596 duration=0.18 action=pass logtype="connection"
Sep  7 13:10:01 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX id=firewall time="2018-09-07 13:10:01" fw="XXXXX-ISSP" tz=+0200 startime="2018-09-07 13:10:00" pri=5 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=810 srcif="vlan3" srcifname="XXXXX" ipproto=udp dstif="Ethernet18" dstifname="FTLAN-XXX" proto=syslog src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX srcport=36147 srcportname=ephemeral_fw_udp srcname=XXXXX.service.noissp.XXXXX.corp srcmac=YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY dst=XXX.CXX.CXX.XXX dstport=514 dstportname=syslog dstname=XXXXX ipv=4 action=block logtype="filter"
Sep  7 13:10:01 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX id=firewall time="2018-09-07 13:10:01" fw="XXXXX-ISSP" tz=+0200 startime="2018-09-07 12:10:00" pri=5 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=273 srcif="vlan6" srcifname="XXXXX" ipproto=udp dstif="vlan6" dstifname="XXXXX" proto=dns_udp src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX srcport=60737 srcportname=XXX-dyn_tcp srcmac=YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dstport=53 dstportname=dns_udp dstname=XXXXX-biznoIssp.biz.noissp modsrc=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX modsrcport=60737 origdst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX origdstport=53 ipv=4 sent=54 rcvd=114 duration=0.00 action=pass logtype="connection"
```

I have tried with read_line to avoid getting an error with line of different sizes:

### Import log file

`rawdata <- read_lines(file="./input.txt")`

### Remove double quotes on each line

`a <- gsub("\"" , "", rawdata)`

### Split the line into multiple strings

`b <- str_split(a, " ")`

But at this point, b is only a vector:

```
> dim(b)
NULL
> length(b)
[1] 10
```

`str_subset(b, "src=")` returns full line instead of single column.
I'm doing something wrong...

How may I extract this information?

Comment: You should show a few lines of the input file, and some code you've tried, explaining why it didn't work.

Comment: The `dim` being NULL doesn't suggest it's a vector, it suggests its a `list`. `str_split` is expected to return a list.

Answer (score 1):

All your code is fine. `str_split` returns a `list`:

```
class(b)
# [1] "list"

length(b)
# [1] 3
lengths(b)
# [1] 41 34 40
```

One list item for each of you input lines, each list item is a vector (raw data split by spaces). We can `sapply` (or `lapply`) `str_subset` to each list item:

```
sapply(b, str_subset, pattern = "src=")
# [[1]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"    "modsrc=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"    "modsrc=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

You might want to modify the regex to exclude the `modrc` entries:

```
sapply(b, str_subset, pattern = "^src=")
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

We could also go directly from `rawdata` without splitting or anything:

```
str_extract_all(rawdata, pattern = "\\bsrc=[^ ]*")
# [[1]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!